# What's the difference between ng-file-upload and angular-file-upload?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

On npm there is a package called [ng-file-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-file-upload) that is on version 5.x and another package called [angular-file-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file-upload) on version 1.6.4. From what I can tell they are the same package but the name was switched over after 1.6.4.

Can anyone elaborate on this?

Comment: I don't think they're both the same. They have different authors. Check it out on Github.

Comment: They seem to be the same. 
Are both from the same author _danialfarid_ but different publishers.
If you check at npm, the github repositories are two different ones from the same author. But if you go here: https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload
You will be redirected to here: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload. **They are the same**. If I were you I would use [ng-file-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-file-upload)

Comment: Thanks gastonmancini. Making sure I'm not going crazy here! Bidhan, they are indeed the same author/github pages.

Comment: Seeing as the collaborators for the latter are not the authors of the library and it's last publish date was 11 months ago, I'd say it's probably an older NPM package of the same thing

Comment: You can always ask the author.